# Chaning each column with strtrim

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
                 V1        V14
1: sp0000001-mRNA-1           
2: sp0000001-mRNA-2           
3: sp0000001-mRNA-3           
4: sp0000005-mRNA-1 GO:0003723
5: sp0000006-mRNA-2 GO:0016021
6: sp0000006-mRNA-1 GO:0016021
```

and I would like to remove with `-mRNA-x` from the first column. How is possible to apply `strtrim(a,9)` to each column?

Comment: Isn't it just `strtrim(df$V1, 9)` ?

Comment: I got a list back rather it changed actually the table `> rm_preffix <- strtrim(interproscan$V1, 9)
> head(rm-preffix)
Error in head(rm - preffix) : object 'preffix' not found
> head(rm_preffix)
[1] "sp0000001" "sp0000001" "sp0000001" "sp0000005" "sp0000006" "sp0000006"`

Comment: I think it has to be `interproscan$V1 <- strtrim(interproscan$V1, 9)` is it correct?